# Список из многомерного массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Помогите выполнить еще одну инструкцию. В функцию приходит строка её нужно отсортировать  , и привести в верхний регистр что-бы получилось , то что в выходном коде. Но плюс ещё один момент - если в массиве встречаются одинаковые фамилии , нужно отсортировать массив по ИМЕНИ а не по фамилии (есть в массиве Madison:STAN и Megan:Stan нужно что-бы они были отобраны по имени а не по фамилии).Результат должен быть такой (ARNO, ANN)(BELL, JOHN)(CORNWELL, ALEX)(DORNY, ABBA)(KERN, LEWIS)(KORN, ALEX)(META, GRACE)(SCHWARZ, VICTORIA)(STAN, MADISON)(STAN, MEGAN)(WAHL, ALEXIS)

```js
function meeting(s) {
    let arr = s.split(';');
    let newArr = [];
    let newarrSorted = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        newArr.push(arr[i].split(':').reverse());
    }

    newArr = newArr.sort();


 for (let j = 0; j < newArr.length; j++) {
     newarrSorted.push(`(${newArr[j].join(', ').toUpperCase()})`);
 }
   return newarrSorted.join('');
}

console.log(meeting("Alexis:Wahl;John:Bell;Victoria:Schwarz;Abba:Dorny;Grace:Meta;Ann:Arno;Madison:STAN;Alex:Cornwell;Lewis:Kern;Megan:Stan;Alex:Korn"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сперва всю строку сделать upperCase, потом сортировать:

`let arr = s.split(';');`

▼ заменить

`let arr = s.toUpperCase().split(';');`

---

Причина: В исходной строке встречаются `Madison:STAN` и `Megan:Stan` а при сортировке в таком виде, между ними встает `Schwarz`:

```js
let arr = [['Schwarz', 'Victoria'], ['STAN', 'Madison'], ['Stan', 'Megan']].sort();

console.log(arr.join(' || ')); // STAN,Madison || Schwarz,Victoria || Stan,Megan

// * sort() без аргументов по умолчанию сортирует всё как строки.
// Если в массиве вместо строк - другие массивы (а у вас именно так),
// они сравниваются в виде строк 'STAN,Madison' < 'Stan,Megan'

console.log( 'STAN' < 'Schwarz' ) // true

console.log( 'Z'.charCodeAt(0) ) // 90
console.log( 'a'.charCodeAt(0) ) // 97

// В кодировке utf-8 все большие буквы идут раньше маленьких,
// поэтому при сравнении - большие буквы всегда 'меньше'.

console.log( 'Z' < 'a' ) // true
```

---

С необязательными изменениями:

```js
function meeting(s) {
  return (
    s.toUpperCase() // <--
      .split(';')
      .map(e => '(' + e.split(':').reverse().join(', ') + ')' )
      .sort()
      .join('')
  );
}

console.log(meeting("Alexis:Wahl;John:Bell;Victoria:Schwarz;Abba:Dorny;Grace:Meta;Ann:Arno;Madison:STAN;Alex:Cornwell;Lewis:Kern;Megan:Stan;Alex:Korn"));
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе Большое ,Оптимус Прайм , без тебя и жизни нет!